# css inlining of two div

Tags: html, css

currently my display looks like that

https://screenshots.firefox.com/kQs0Rz21PMhpDyDE/localhost

I want add Education link to be inline with education label but in backward by clicking this link I am   showing display none div

https://screenshots.firefox.com/tKtl1rcncgKSp23B/localhost

If I use margin top to make both inline it hides behind my display none div

what should I do

my code is

```html
<div class= "row" id="mainContainer">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
   <label for="Education">Education</label>
  </div>
  <div class=class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="nestedFeilds"  style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left; display: none">
         <a href="" style="color: red;margin-left: auto; ">Delete Education</a>
   <input  type="text" placeholder="School Name" class="form-control" id="School_Name"  required="" name="School_Name[]">
   |<br>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Feild of Study" class="form-control" id="feild_Name"  required="" name="feild_Name[]">
   <br>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Degree" class="form-control" id="Degree_Name"  required="" name="Degree_Name[]">
   <br>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class= "row" id="2ndmainContainer">
 <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4"></div>
 <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="showhere"  style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left;"></div>
  <div  style="margin-left: 120px; float:left;"><a id="addNew"> Add Education</a></div>
 </div>
         </form>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

the complete content of div with id nested field will be append in div with id showhere

Comment: kindly some one can help me

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you please restate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left` to `#mainContainer`.

```html
<div class="row" id="mainContainer" style="float:left">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
    <label for="Education">Education</label>
  </div>
  <div class=class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="nestedFeilds" style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left; display: none">
    <a href="" style="color: red;margin-left: auto; ">Delete Education</a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="School Name" class="form-control" id="School_Name" required="" name="School_Name[]"> |
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Feild of Study" class="form-control" id="feild_Name" required="" name="feild_Name[]">
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Degree" class="form-control" id="Degree_Name" required="" name="Degree_Name[]">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="2ndmainContainer">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="showhere" style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left;"></div>
  <div style="margin-left: 120px; float:left;"><a id="addNew"> Add Education</a></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And I strongly recommend that you use an external CSS stylesheet.

> Link to an external style sheet:
>
> ```
> <head>
>   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
> </head>
> ```

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp):

Comment: Umm, it's working here. Could you post a link to your site?

Comment: sir it is on localhost of my laptop